# Re-use common project resources across projects

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, prettier

When setting up a nodejs project I'd like to end up with some common stuff in those projects. Like a prettier setup, good tsconfig, .eslint and .eslintignore and also vscode settings for debugging the project which I commit to the repo as well.

This is all well and good but when you're outputting a few hundred of these artifacts (basically nodejs + apollo + graphql apis), those project setups become more then a little redundant. That means all version numbers for typescript, prettier, eslint, jest and so on are in every package.json and each project becomes slowly 'older'.

There are some good ways of generating projects obviously, like yeoman, but is there a way to re-use those configurations across projects without including the configurations in every repository?

EDIT:
Ow yeah; I get that I can install things like lint, jest and prettier globally on a workstation. But then I restrict the settings to myself instead of sharing it with colleagues which including it in my project provides.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik node (actually it's rather npm) does not offer a built-in option to achieve what you're looking for.

However, there's [this](https://github.com/Cosium/dry-dry) nice little wrapper around npm, allowing you to define a "parent"-package.json which child-projects can inherit from - this is in fact very similar to maven's parent-pom.

Comment: Very interesting. And I guess I can add prettier and eslint configs to the package.json...

Comment: At least for `eslint` I know that you can put its config under the `eslintConfig` property in your package.json, not sure about `prettier` though.